# How do i write a federated plugin in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins

I am writing a federated plugin in Flutter but acc to [url_launcher plugin](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master_archive/packages/url_launcher) I have to create app_facing_package, platform_package and platform_interface_package but I don't know what to write in these packages

in docs, there is a command

```
flutter create --org com.example --template=plugin --platforms=android,ios,linux,macos,windows -a kotlin hello
```

but it creates a normal plugin, not a federated plugin

Comment: There's [an open issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43284) about this